# Haskell & atom : cabal build fails on "unrecognized option `--only'"

Tags: haskell, build, atom-editor, cabal

I get this error while trying to build a project using cabal, on centOS 7.
ghc version is 7.6.3, cabals one is 1.16.1.0 for cabal-install, and 1.16.0 for the cabal library.

the cabal file follows:

```
-- Initial premier_programme.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                premierProgramme
version:             1.0
synopsis:            exemple de test
-- description:
-- license:
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Olivier
maintainer:          abc@laposte.net
-- copyright:
category:            Development
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.8

executable premierProgramme
  main-is: lanceur.hs
  -- other-modules:
  build-depends:       base ==4.6.*
```

and the haskell file is:

```
module Main where

fibo :: Integer -> Integer
fibo 0  = 1
fibo 1 = 1
fibo n = fibo (n-1) + fibo (n-2)

-- | This is the documentation for 'square', which
--   uses the (*) operator from "Prelude".
--   It multiplies the @x@ argument against itself.
square :: Integer -> Integer
square x = x*x

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Hello World"
  print $ fibo 10
  print $ square 17
```

thanks

Comment: I get "cabal: unrecognized option `--only'", in atom

Comment: what is the command line (that atom uses to call cabal) exactly? I'd say it's looking like a version mismatch, your setup (ghc-7.6) looks quite old and likely is not supported by atom's haskell mode.

Comment: I have no idea. It should be in the docs, or the source. I'd say that the minimal requirements for running atom/haskell are somewhat under-documented at https://github.com/atom-haskell/ide-haskell#requirements . But did you follow these steps? If yes, and it still does not work, then file a bug there.

Comment: Yes, I saw it before. I recognize I don't have a minimal toolchain installed : it's a complete install of ghc + cabal + other common libraries. I thought that if there were more libraries installed, it wouldn't be annoying. Do you think that was a mistake?

Comment: Try (in a shell)  'stack install stylish-haskell' etc (or 'cabal install ...') as mentioned on web site.

Comment: Well, I'm tired, I will do it tomorrow. Good night!